# XLRD vs Win32 COM performance comparison

Tags: python, excel, csv, win32com

I have this huge `Excel (xls)` file that I have to read data from. I tried using the `xlrd` library, but is pretty slow. I then found out that by converting the `Excel` file to `CSV` file manually and reading the `CSV` file is orders of magnitude faster.

But I cannot ask my client to save the `xls` as `csv` manually every time before importing the file. So I thought of converting the file on the fly, before reading it.

Has anyone done any benchmarking as to which procedure is faster:

- Open the `Excel` file with with the `xlrd` library and save it as `CSV` file, or
- Open the `Excel` file with `win32com` library and save it as `CSV` file?

I am asking because the slowest part is the opening of the file, so if I can get a performance boots from using `win32com` I would gladly try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is off topic as you are asking recommendations of software libraries. Why don't you try benchmarking? Come back then with specific troubleshooting of modules.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to read the file frequently, I think it is better to save it as CSV. Otherwise, just read it on the fly.

for performance issue, I think win32com outperforms. however, considering cross-platform compatibility, I think xlrd is better.
win32com is more powerful. With it, one can handle Excel in all ways (e.g. reading/writing cells or ranges). 
However, if you are seeking a quick file conversion, I think pandas.read_excel also works.

I am using another package xlwings. so I am also interested with a comparison among these packages.

to my opinion,
I would use pandas.read_excel to for quick file conversion.
If demanding more processing on Excel, I would choose win32com.